# ORA-01791: oracle join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I want to know how to organize this code in a way where I'm only getting the data from customer. my problem is I'm getting repeated data from rental which is against what I need.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT C.CUSTOMER_ID , (C.FIRST_NAME|| ' ' || C.LAST_NAME) "Customer Name" 
 FROM CUSTOMER C 
   JOIN RENTAL R ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = R.CUSTOMER_ID 
 ORDER BY C.LAST_NAME;
```

exactly I should get 599 rows, when this is giving me 16044 rows.

Comment: Is it possible that any first or last names have excess leading or trailing whitespace?

Comment: What do you mean by "repeated" data?  Can you make this question minimal and reproducible?

Comment: At a guess, I would say that without using the `DISTINCT` keyword, you are getting 16044 rows, and with the keyword you are getting the `ORA-01791` error, because you need to order by one of the columns in the `DISTINCT` set of columns. Refer to the answer by @kaushiknayak.

Comment: Are you asking about `ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression` or about the number of rows you are getting, due presumably to `customer_id` being unique?

Answer (score 1):

Fetch only distinct customers from rental to join with customer. I think the error you received - `ORA-01791` is because of using `ORDER BY C.LAST_NAME` . either use `ORDER BY "Customer Name"`  or `ORDER BY 2`

```
SELECT 
        C.CUSTOMER_ID , 
        (C.FIRST_NAME|| 
        ' '          || 
                C.LAST_NAME) "Customer Name" 
FROM 
        CUSTOMER C 
JOIN 
        ( SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID FROM RENTAL 
        ) R ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = R.CUSTOMER_ID 
ORDER BY 
        2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with

```
SELECT C.CUSTOMER_ID , (C.FIRST_NAME|| ' ' || C.LAST_NAME) "Customer Name" 
FROM
CUSTOMER C
WHERE
C.CUSTOMER_ID IN
(SELECT DISTINCT CUSTOMER_ID FROM RENTAL)
ORDER BY 
C.CUSTOMER_ID
```